# Al comparar dos booleanos iguales devuelve verdadero pero no al comparar dos objetos iguales no ¿Por qué?

Tags: javascript, es2016, ecmascript-7

En el siguiente código se usa la función Boolean para devolver un valor. Si se hace una comparación estricta del resultado de dos funciones que devuelven el mismo valor el resultado es verdadero, pero si se comparan dos objetos creados con usando new Boolean el resultado es falso.

```js
var salidas = [ 
  Boolean(true),
  Boolean(true) === Boolean(true),
  new Boolean(true) === new Boolean(true),
]

console.log(salidas.join('\n'));
```

¿A qué se debe que al comparar dos objetos que han sido creados usando el mismo código el resultado es falso? ¿Cómo explica esto la ECMAScript 2016?

---

Intuyo que la respuesta va por lo siguiente

- `Boolean(true)` devuelve un dato primitivo de tipo booleano con valor `true`
- `new Bolean(true)` devuelve un objeto que hereda las propiedades del objeto `Boolean`.
- Cada vez que se llama `new Bolean(true)` se tienen objetos que tienen la misma estructura heredada del objeto Boolean, no confundir con el primitivo Boolean.
- Por estructura heredada me refiero a ambos objetos tendrán las propiedades al el menos de nombre, sin embargo, hay algo que hace distintos a los dos objetos y que por ende una comparación estricta de estos devuelve `false`.

¿Qué es lo que hace distintas a dos objetos que heredan propiedades del mismo objeto?

---

Nota:

Según entiendo, en términos coloquiales podríamos decir que los dos objetos son instancias de la misma clase, sin embargo, no estoy seguro que en términos estrictos esto sea correcto pues JavaScript si bien es un lenguaje orientado a objetos, hasta la versión 6 no se tenía implentado el manejo de clases, si no que que se trata de un lenguaje tipado. En ECMAScript 2015 (versión 6) se ha introducido class, véase [14 ECMAScript Language: Functions and Classes](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes) para la versión 2015 y [14 ECMAScript Language: Functions and Classes](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes) para la versión 2016.

---

Al parecer aquí los conceptos clave a diferenciar son igualdad e identidad

Por **igualdad**, entiéndase que dos cosas son iguales cuando estos cuentan con los mismos valores y cuando se trata de objetos cuentan con las mismas propiedades y estas con los mismos valores

Por **identidad**, entiéndase que dos cosas son idénticas, es decir que no son dos cosas, sino que se trata de la misma cosa, ambas son una y sólo una cosa.

Dos instancias de un objeto no son idénticas, aunque se hayan creado prácticamente al mismo tiempo, son dos cosas independientes.

Cabe mencionar que "JavaScript puro" no ofrece identificadores únicos para los objetos, pero alguna librerías o frameworks podrían hacerlo.

En las ECMAScript no encontré que se hablara de lo anterior, pero sí en cierta medida en [Equality comparisons and sameness](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes)

Nota: En enlace anterior apunta a la versión en inglés pues la de español no incluye referencias a las versiones más recientes de ECMAScript siendo que la de inglés si lo hace.

---

Pregunta relacionada

- [¿Cómo se debe comparar un objeto en javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57528/65)

Comment: Alomejor no tiene nada que ver, pero, yo diría que "eso que les hace diferentes", es la dirección de memoria que están usando.

Comment: Quise decir que sí suena lógico. La primer respuesta ha sido actualizada hace mención de la posición de memoria.

Comment: Es tan simple como el operador que usas. Estás haciendo una comparación de **identidad**, por ende, no se hace ninguna conversión antes ni durante la conversión como ocurre con el operador de **igualdad**. Una comparación de *identidad* iguala **tipos y valores** si son primitivos y, si son objetos compara **referencias**. Como dato curioso, hay otro algoritmo de igualdad, el cual implementa [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/is).

Comment: Lo de igualdad e identidad lo agregué a la pregunta hace unas horas :) En parte la confusión se debe en que hay literatura que llama a `===` igualdad estricta y pues es para algunos no está del todo claro. "Lamentablemente" las referencias no se pueden ver "a simple vista" en "javascript puro" así que uno tiene que usar la imaginación, salvo que se esté usando algún engine o framework que asigne id's a los objetos y ofrezca una interface para hacerlos visibles

Answer (score 8):

**Actualización**

Ya veo por dónde va lo de tu pregunta. En JavaScript los objetos son guardados por refencia, por lo tanto, lo que debe estar comparando son las posiciones de memoria y estas son distintas para cada instancia.

---

Pues, como yo lo veo, el operador `new` crea instancias de un objeto. En mi opinión sería un error considerar que dos instancias sean exactamente iguales. Lo mismo ocurre con otros objetos:

```js
console.log(new Array() === new Array());
console.log(new Object() === new Object());
```

La forma correcta de comparar las nuevas instancias es con su valor:

```js
var salidas = [ 
  Boolean(true),
  Boolean(true) === Boolean(true),
  (new Boolean(true)).valueOf() === (new Boolean(true)).valueOf(),
]

console.log(salidas.join('\n'));
```

Comment: Intuitivamente entiendo lo de dos instancias no son iguales, ¿existe alguna propiedad que sea diferente? ¿Sabes si esto está descrito en la ECMAScript 2016 de forma clara?

Comment: @Rubén no entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres con lo de las propiedades, si son creadas usando el mismo contructor, deberían tener las mismas propiedades pero. obviamente, el valor es distinto. No estoy seguro si está documentado en el ES.

Comment: @César tu respuesta es muy completa; puedo complementarla?

Comment: @JackNavaRow claro amigo, de eso se trata :-)

Comment: @César: Sugiero pasar "la actualización" a la parte superior. Aprovecho para compartirte que en lo personal trato de evitar títulos como "Actualización" "Edición" sobre todo cuando es redundante al enlace "editada hace ...".

Comment: @Rubén sugerencia aceptada, estimado.

Comment: Me parece que lo que de la posición de memoria es el quid del asunto, ya sólo le falta una referencia a una fuente confiable para hacerla una respuesta "perfecta".

Answer (score 3):

El error radica en que `Boolean(true)` devuelve un valor `booleano` un dato primitivo, no obstante hacer `new Boolean(true)` el valor devuelto es un `objeto` que envuelve el dato primitivo `true`

```
typeof Boolean(true) // boolean
typeof new Boolean(true) // object
```

El comparar dos objetos, se hace normalmente por referencia, es decir hacer

```
objA === objB
```

Devuelve `true` sí y sólo sí `objB` es un `alias` de `objA`

Así que si quieres comparar objetos basados en sus propiedades, deberás implementarlo, como en el siguiente snippet

```js
Object.prototype.igualA = function(obj)
{
 var _this = this // extiende el alcance
 var mismo_constructor = _this.constructor === obj.constructor

 var mismas_propiedades = function()
 {
  var propiedades = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(_this)
  for(var i in propiedades)
  {
   var propiedad = propiedades[i]
   if(_this[propiedad] !== obj[propiedad]){ return false } 
  } 
  return true
 }()

 return mismo_constructor && mismas_propiedades
}

var x = new Boolean(true)
var y = new Boolean(true)
console.log(x.igualA(y))
```

Comment: ¿Cómo para qué? Me refiero a que falta incluir una descripción del código :) Por otro lado, estoy preguntando por lo que hace a dos objetos ser diferentes no por la forma de compararlos.

Comment: @Rubén listo he actualizado.

Comment: Me parece que resulta confusa la explicación, ya que primero dices que al comparar dos objetos se hace mediante  variables pero estas variables no son objetos, son referencias a objetos, luego más abajo dices que sólo devuelve true si son alias del mismo objeto. La pregunta es sobre comparar dos objetos que han sido creados con el mismo código.

Comment: dos objetos son alias uno de otro si guardan la misma referencia a memoria, jamás usé el término "variable"

Comment: No usaste el término variable pero estrictamente, objA y objB son variables no objetos.

Answer (score 1):

En Javascript los objetos son creados por referencia. Eso significa que cuando se hace `obj1 == obj2` lo que se compara es la referencia, o sea devolverá `true` solo si se trata del mismo objeto, es decir, `obj1` y `obj2` apuntan a la misma dirección en memoria.

Para verificar la igualdad de objetos de una misma clase, debe definirse un metodo `equals(other)`. Por ejemplo

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;

    var self = this;
    this.equals = function(other){
        return (other instanceof Person) && self.name == other.name;
    }
}

var p1 = new Person("Juan");
var p2 = new Person("Pedro");
var p3 = new Person("Juan");

alert(p1.equals(p2)); // Devuleve false
alert(p1.equals("Juan")); // Devuelve false, "Juan" no es una instancia de la clase Person, sino un string
alert(p1.equals(p3)); // Devuelve true
```

Imprime:

```
false
false
true
```