# Script recorrido de filas y columnas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, operador, comparaciones

estoy realizando un script para la hoja de calculo de google que recorra las filas y las columnas de en busca de unos valores en concreto y me los cuente, para posteriormente escribirlo en otra hoja.

Este es el script que tengo ahora mismo:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calvià");
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var nombres = 2;
  var parque = 2;
  var posiciong = 2;
  var posiciongr = 2;


  for (r=7; r<lastrow+1; r++){

      var G = 0;
      var GR = 0;
      var range = ss.getRange(r,1).getValue();

      if (range!=0){

        var range2 = ss.getRange(r,4).getValue();
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras").getRange(nombres, 1).setValue(range);
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras").getRange(parque, 2).setValue(range2);
        nombres = nombres + 1;
        parque = parque +1;

        for (c=6; c<93; c++){

          var rangec = ss.getRange(r,c).getValue().toString;

          if (rangec="G"){

            G = G + 1;

          }if (rangec="GR"){

            GR = GR + 1;

          }

        }

        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras").getRange(posiciong, 3).setValue(G);
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContadorHoras").getRange(posiciongr, 4).setValue(GR);
        posiciong = posiciong + 1;
        posiciongr = posiciongr + 1;

      }

  }

}
```

Todo funciona bien asta que llega añado el segundo for, con el primer for, recorro  las filas y con el segundo, las columnas de cada fila buscando unos valores y contandolos, mi problema esta en que no consigo que funcione bien este segundo for, todo el rato me dice que G Y GR son 87.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando el operador de asignación `=` en lugar de alguno de los operadores de comparación de igualdad, `==` ó `===`.

En otras palabras, cambia

```
rangec="G"
```

por

```
rangec=="G"
```

lo mismo para las otras comparaciones de igualdad

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo se deben comparar dos objetos en javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57528/65)